# Dynamic range using Vuelidate's between validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I currently have data attribute with

```
data() {
  return {
    stats: {
      limit: 100,
      score: 0
    }
  }
}
```

then I want my validation to be between 0 to the value of `limit` from data attribute
I'm currently using [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) for validating attributes.

```
import { required, between } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

validations: {
  stats: {
    score: {
      between: between(0, this.stats.limit)
    }
  }
}
```

But this is not currently working. I'm currently getting
`Cannot read property limit of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the context of vuelidate's validators is not the component instance. But, since vuelidate passes the component context trough function context, you can replace it with a custom function.

```
import { required, between } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

function customBetween(value) {
  return between(0, this.stats.limit)(value)
}

validations: {
  stats: {
    score: {
      between: customBetween
    }
  }
}
```